# maven release plugin and command line arguments

Tags: maven-release-plugin

I am trying to do a non-interactive maven release:

```
mvn clean install \
  -PmyAssembly,attach-installer \
  -DcustomerFlag=simple \
  release:clean \
  release:prepare \
  release:perform \
  -DreleaseVersion=1.0.1 \
  -DdevelopmentVersion=1.0.2-SNAPSHOT \
  -Dtag=my-project-1.0.1
```

But the property `-DcustomerFlag=simple` is not set when running `perform` only when running `prepare`.

Do I need to specify all command line arguments and profile twice, once for `prepare` and once for `perform` ?

Alternatively I guess I can just skip the `perform` step and do a regular build/deploy afterwards with the parameters I need from the generated tag.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

None of the -D args from the commandline are passed by the maven-release-plugin to the inner Maven calls. You should use `-Darguments="-DcustomerFlag=simple"` to get  the expected result, see [arguments](http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#arguments)

Comment: I had to use "-Darguments=-DcustomerFlag=simple" to get it to work on Bamboo.

Comment: How to add multiple arguments? e.g. customerFlag AND skipTests?

Comment: Just like on the commandline, with space separator in the value, e.g.`-Darguments="-DcustomerFlag=simple -DskipTests"`

Comment: How to pass multiple arguments to release plugin. http://maven.apache.org/maven-release/maven-release-plugin/prepare-mojo.html#arguments

Comment: To pass multiple ones (especially from build tools like jenkins/bamboo/gitlab), use `"-Darguments=-Dprop1=${dynamicEnvProp1} -Dprop2Static=alwaysThis"`. The `"` quotes before the `-Darguments` - and at the very end of course - are crucial here. Otherwise you might end up with only the first property set!

Comment: Another hint: if you run release:prepare and release:perform separately, double check to add those params to the correct invocation of the goal you're trying to provide them to. Most likely it's release:perform, as release:prepare doesn't spawn a child maven instance as far as i know - thus params can be passed to it the usual way.

Comment: One (hopefully last) hint: If you plan to use mvn:release/prepare in bamboo and then deploy the result-artifact directly, make sure to share the right artifact. It usually will reside in `/target/checkout/target/`, while in `/target` you'll find the jar from release:prepare, that shouldn't really be used for any furhter processing as far as i know. Maybe its also a good idea to ditch the maven release plugin altogether, see: https://axelfontaine.com/blog/dead-burried.html